# My answer to a question asking for a Sunni perspective was deleted although it is from a Sunni perspective

Tags: discussion, moderation, etiquette, deleted-answer

I posted an answer to the Question :

[Can we ask another person who is more faithful than us to ask our demands from Allah ? is this Tavassol or not?(Sunni view )](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17112/can-we-ask-another-person-who-is-more-faithful-than-us-to-ask-our-demands-from-a/17113?noredirect=1#comment31686_17113)

It was deleted by a moderator with the reason

> "The question is now explicitly asking for a Sunni view. This does not answer the question."

1. I would like to know why the moderator said "The question is asking explicitly for Sunni view".
2. My answer is a Sunni answer (see [Barelvi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barelvi)).
   It might not be the case that all Sunni share this view, however it does not mean it is not *a* Sunni view.
   Also the answer I gave was straight from the Qur'an.
   So I would like to conclude that, I did indeed answer the question from a Sunni perspective.

I think it would have been appropriate if I was first told to edit the answer to clarify that it is a Sunni view, if that was unclear at first.

I propose that my answer be undeleted and I can edit my answer if there is some sort of ambiguity for the readers.

Answer (score 6):

> I would first of like to know why the moderator say "The question is asking explicitly for Sunni view"

How many reasons do you need? It says it wants a Sunni view in the title. It's tagged [sunni](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sunni). The question body cites a Sunni source it's asking in reference to. Clearly it is explicitly looking for an answer representative of Sunni views. Anything not so would be out of scope.

As for editing, you currently already have the chance to edit. You'll find the edit link below your post just as it was before deletion. If your post is brought clearly in scope for the question it can then be undeleted. This is standard operating order for SE sites. For closed questions, fix first, then re-open later. For answers that are out of scope, fix first, un-delete later. If the issues are not addressed there is no point in restoring a post.

It sounds to me like your main issue is that you need to explicitly identify that your answer only represents a subset of Sunni Muslims and not try to pawn it off as a "universally true" view as if all Sunnis [ought to] believe that way. To properly answer the question you would also need to include something about what the *rest* of Sunnis believe so the question actually gets fully covered according to all Sunnis in general not just for Barelvis.

Comment: I don't think there is need to also express all other Sunni views in the answer. It is sufficient that the answer is from _a_ Sunni perspective. An answer does not need to be comprehensive. The author might not be knowledgeable about them and covering all of them can be impracticable. The answer could be edited to make it explicit that this is only one of them. There was no need for deletion. I think deletion was based on lack of knowledge on the moderator's part that there are such Sunni views. The more appropriate action would be asking them OP to clarify if it is a Sunni view.

Answer (score 2):

Forgive my lack of knowledge, but last I checked the fundamental difference between the Sunnis and the Shi'ites was neither their positions on Wilayat nor Tavassol, rather it was the belief in [Imamah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imamah_(Shia_doctrine)), the idea that the leaders of the Ummah — the Imams — are divinely appointed by Allah: Shi'ites believe in it and Sunnis do not, period.  So when I see quotes like,

> The Ulul Amr Minkum are the people Allah has chosen after the prophet to have authority (Wilayah) over the ummah. These are the Imams,

then yes, I come to the conclusion that you are writing from a Shi'ite perspective.  And I think it's reasonable to assume that all the votes you have received to-date on that post were again based on its representing a Shi'ite perspective, as you nowhere in the post indicated that you were writing or intending to write a Barelvi post.

Combine this with the fact that the answer to this post is word-for-word the same as [your answer to another question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/17088/22), a question which is also not asking for a Barelvi perspective; as worded, that question appears to be *explicitly* asking for Shi'ite apologism.

And even if you were actually intending to write from a Barelvi perspective from the get-go (rather than trying to shoe-horn a Shi'ite answer into a question that isn't asking for one), the question is *not even asking* for the *Barelvi* perspective: It is asking for the *Sunni* perspective.  Unless you're willing to argue that the Barelvi position on this matter is the *only* Sunni perspective, it is at best an *item* and not an *answer*.

Comment: Umm... The Barelvies in Pakistan refer to Hazrat Ali, Hazrat Hasan, Hazrat Hussain, Hazrat Zain-ul Abideen as Imams when they speak of them. Example; "Imam Ali". Its just a matter of linguistics... But I think more than that, they belive that these people are even the Imam's of the Wali-Allah's, hence they are called Imam. The Barelvis also believe that Wali-Allah's are chosen by Allah. So that was a wrong assertion you made Sir. Also barelvi's are Sunni Muslims so i think it suffices to give their opinion. But I do agree that this leaves the answer lacking comprehensivity.

Comment: Please refer to the Shajra-e-Attaria Qadria: (http://data2.dawateislami.net/Data/Books/Download/en/pdf/2009/521-1.pdf)  ... And please refer to page 5. Here you will see the Shajra(Family Tree) of Wilayat for the Barelvi muslims.

Comment: @Ali I don't see how that's remotely relevant to my answer.  Your source does *nothing* to demonstrate that Barelvis associate An-Nisa 59's "Ulul Amr Minkum" with the Imams, a claim which your answer *clearly* posits and which I *clearly* explained was a major factor in me actioning it as I did.

Answer (score 2):

Let me add something to what Caleb has written.

The fact that you use Quran does not always mean you are not ansering from a Shia (or a Sunni) perspective. This is specially true if they disagree about the interpretation of the relevant verses.

When someone asks for a Sunni prereproductive it means they want to know how Sunnis *actually* view the issue. If you are not a Sunni yourself and your answer is not expressing a view expressed by a Sunni scholar, then you are not expressing a Sunni perspective. It is not sufficient that you base your answer on sources accepted by Sunnis to express an opinion on the issue that is not expressed by them. It won't be a genuine Sunni view.

In summary, if you are not a Sunni and you are not expressing an opinion which is expressed by a Sunni scholar (you should have direct references, not indirect references through say Shia studies of those sources, if you have direct references to Sunni sources expressing the view you should cite them) then you should respect the will of the person asking the question and not answer the question.

Now if your answer is genuinely a Sunni view, then please edit your answer and provide references and then flag it to be undeleted.

PS: the reason the moderator deleted your answer is because he thought that it is not  a Sunni perspective and therefore an apologistic answer, and apologistic behavior is forbidden on this site. And it is indeed hard to see that was not the case. Since it is clear that it is not *the* mainstream Sunni view and many Sunnis would disagree with it, it would have been more appropriate for you to explicitly say that this is the view of the particular Sunni group. 
(I agree it would have been more appropriate to ask you first to clarify before deletion, assuming that you don't have a history of appologistic behavior on the site).

Comment: Fair enough. I agree. I think only a Sunni can give the best answer from a sunni perspective. I tried to give a Sunni perspective. But somehow bias may have trickled down, because barelvi perspective of Wilayat and Shia perspective is quite similar, although there probably are some fundamental differences. But because me writing as a shia of the barelvi perspective... which is so similar. Unintentional bias might have been felt in my answer and hence it was closed, i guess.